# Neural Network for figuring out combinations of variables

Tags: matrix, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, linear-algebra

I'm trying to create a neural network that will learn the rules of matrix multiplication. I've tried to do it directly, by having a training set of two matrices (2x2) and their corresponding product (2x2).  I tried to train the network by feeding it this training data and seeing if it would be able to pick up the rules of multiplication on its own.  This didn't seem to work.

I'm now thinking that about making it learn matrix multiplication by making the network focus on the sequence of operations necessary to do multiplication.  For example, if we have two matrices A and B, it would tell me that C11 would be A11*B11 + A12*B21 etc.  This would be the first output (of 4) that I would expect from the network.  I've been using python scikit for the neural network.  I'm having trouble framing the problem correctly.  The way I'm visualizing it is that I have 8 inputs (2 2x2 matrices) and 4 outputs (the multiplied matrix) for my training data.  I would like to use this data to learn a sequence of operations without telling it the operations beforehand as this would defeat the purpose of the network.  How should I arrange my training data and network to figure out the rules of multiplication?

Comment: Would be nearly impossible initially, since an ANN will try to discover the solution vector of parameters, which will depend on the data.  It would be like regression, where e.g. the solution vector (regression coefficients) are b0=2.3 and b1=24.8 for a data set -- however, in this case, what will the numeric parameters have to do with sequential steps of matrix multiplication?  A way to exploit an ANN for this, would be to view the ANN as the function(equation).  I would look at Wolfram's Alpha to see if their system can do this.

Comment: Hi. Could you post your code with scikit-learn ? Did you use a linear activation function for your output layer ?

Comment: @Khaled[Here's(http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241519/implementing-a-neural-network-to-learn-matrix-multiplication) a post I made on cross validated without much success.  The code is over there. It wasn't giving me anything useful so I didn't bother posting it.  I was trying to figure out a new approach without focusing on the code.

Comment: @wrtsvkrfm Would a different training set be better?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with ANNs, but I would think even multiplication of two real numbers might be slightly tricky to learn with a small network. Does you ANN solve basic 1x1 matrix multiplication?

Comment: Doubt it.   ANNs solve problems for parameters, not sequential time-dependent steps.   If you are trying to determine what algorithms were applied to a given set of data then look into cryptography, which tries to shortcut everything.  Recall, ANNs are actually quite expensive computationally, and while I have a lot of experience with ANNs, they tend to not turn out out to be the "goto" algorithm, once you learn about a lot of other approaches.

Comment: Related: [Can deep neural network approximate multiplication function without normalization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/217703) and [How to build a Neural Network to multiply two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52660944).