# How to build a Neural Network to multiply two numbers

Tags: python-3.x, performance, scikit-learn, neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to build a neural network which would multiply 2 numbers. To do the same, I took help of scikit-learn. I am going for a neural network with 2 hidden layers, (5, 3) and ReLU as my activation function.

I have defined my `MLPRegressor` as follows:

```
X = data.drop('Product', axis=1)
y = data['Product']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 3), activation="relu", learning_rate="adaptive", max_iter=500000, verbose=True, validation_fraction=0.25)
```

Here, `data` is the dataframe which contains the 3 columns, 2 random numbers and 1 Product column. 
The issue is the loss that I get is of order 10^14. How do I reduce this loss, improve my model performance and what all possible changes can help me out in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in NNs. I would do log-tranform of the inputs, then feed them into a network, then exponetiate the output. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that an NN with only two hidden layers is not sufficient to perform a multiplication of arbitrary numbers. Note that a multiplication of N * M is equal to the M-fold addition of N. There are neural networks that can perform an addition, but you have to consider the general conditions. Furthermore, you have to decide how the inputs and outputs of your network are defined: Do you want two input neurons and one output neuron, or do you want the two multiplicants to be binary (as a vector) in the net? I think you would have to normalize your input values if you gave decimal values in two input neurons.

Comment: My data consists of decimal points, ranging from -10000 to 10000. I have normalized my input training set. Do I need to normalize my output values too? Plus, I want my neural net to have two input node and one output node, such that when I predict say [2, -3], it gives me approximately expected output.

Comment: Of course, the output values must also be normalized. Please note that, depending on the data type, a rounding error can occur and your training data already contains errors. Just out of interest: why would you want to use a neural net for this task at all? If it's just to learn something about it, there are probably much better examples.

Comment: The normalization of output should be on the basis of `scaler.fit(X_train)` or should be done independently? 
Also I want to see the limitations of neural network, if it can approximate any function given enough capability, can it do this simple task by learning from data.

Comment: Although I didn't get the fact how will normalizing the output affect the outcome.

Comment: I haven't worked with scikit learn yet. However, it is important that the weights at the connections of your neurons are decisive for the result. At the same time, their range of validity (and especially the range in which they do not work "binary" (on/off)) is limited by the activation function used. If You now use standardized input values, but still want to get high output values, the weights must therefore become very large. Therefore, it makes sense to normalize both input and output values.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this. This is a neural network that approximate the multiplication function to multiply numbers in the range of 1000 - 10000, and it could work really well if the range of numbers is limited. Here is the [gist link](https://gist.github.com/palashahuja/369c3b31d479f9fde2c7d11caec8bcf4)